# Can't understand np.partition

Tags: python, numpy

I tried understanding the function but the output seems weird.

```
array = np.array([9, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 1, 5])
print(np.partition(array, kth=0))
```

That's the output I'm getting for some reason:
`[1 2 7 4 6 3 8 9 5]`

Expected to get:
`[X X X X X X X X 9]`

What am I missing?

Comment: The `1` has been moved to the front.

Answer (score 1):

From the description in the [numpy.partition](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) documentation, `[1 2 7 4 6 3 8 9 5]` is a correct partition of your input array for `kth=0`:

> Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way that the value of the element in k-th position is in the position it would be in a sorted array. All elements smaller than the k-th element are moved before this element and all equal or greater are moved behind it. The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is undefined.

I think the confusion is in the ambiguous description of *kth*. That's the index *after* the partition operation, not before. So, in your example, `kth=0` doesn't refer to the value at index 0 of the input array (9), it refers to whatever value would be at index 0 of a sorted array of the same values, in this case 1.

Any arrangement matching `[1 X X X X X X X X]` is valid.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. I wonder when will it be useful to use this function instead of sorting the whole array? Is it just to save time on sorting or is there another more delicate reason?

Comment: @IdoBenArtzi I remember that partition is one step in the [Quicksort alogirithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), so it at least has that application. I'm not sure where else it's used by itself, but it is only O(n), so it's faster than any full sorting algorithm. Maybe if you only care about one value (min, max, or midpoint)?